# Ordering Data by datetime Entry in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have content_date row in my table that uses the datetime field type. I would like to order my data (content_items) using this field.

**models/content_item.rb**

```
class ContentItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :calendar
end
```

**models/calendar.rb**

```
class Calendar < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :content_items
end
```

**controllers/content_items_controller.rb**

```
  def index
    @calendar = Calendar.find(params[:calendar_id])
  end
```

I tried this, but had no success:

**controllers/content_items_controller.rb**

```
  def index
    @calendar = Calendar.find(params[:calendar_id])
    @content_item = @calendar.content_items.order(content_date: :desc)
  end
```

Github Link: https://github.com/JeremyEnglert/baked

Comment: `content_date` is a field or the `ContentItem`? If so, the latest query is correct. What error are you experiencing?

Comment: Correct, content_date is a field of the content_items. There isn't an error, the data simply isn't changing order at all.

Comment: @JeremyE Your query should work.. Show the SQL of this `@calendar.content_items.order(content_date: :desc)` from your console..

Comment: which database you are using ? SQLite has issues with datetime

Comment: @KaranPurohit, I'm using whatever comes with a default Rails install. (Still new to Rails).

Comment: @jeremyE your ruby version?

Comment: I added a Github link to the original post, just in case that is helpful. I find it odd that he console throws an error, but the actual page doesn't.

Comment: @JeremyE I checked the GitHub repo. It seems Ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should fix the issue:

```
@content_item = @calendar.content_items.order('content_date desc')
```

**UPDATE**:

I checked your Github repo. You are not using the instance variable in the controller to display the content items. You have to change:

**app/views/content_items/index.html.erb**

```
<% @calendar.content_items.each do |content_item| %>
```

to:

```
<% @content_item.each do |content_item| %>
```

Comment: No luck. It doesn't throw an error, but the data doesn't sort.

Answer (score 0):

```
@content_items = Calendar.includes(:content_items).order('content_items.content_date desc')
```

This will solve your problem.

Comment: This is incorrect. It will simply return the calendar matching given id, with all the items lazy-loaded.

Comment: I added that to my existing index method and no luck. If I remove  '@calendar = Calendar.find(params[:calendar_id])', it led to other errors.

Comment: just execute the above in rails console and check